# Crash at MKMapItem.placemark.coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am developing an app into Swift language, which is required to search map data. 
So, I have implemented search using **MKLocalSearch**. Search work perfectly. I add search result into one array.
Whenever I try to add **Annotation** of one result on Map then it crashed.

**code for search is here**

```
var searchRequest : MKLocalSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = address
        searchRequest.region = self.mapView.region

        var search : MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
 search.startWithCompletionHandler { (
            response, err) -> Void in
            //ARRAY IN WHICH I STORE RESULT
            self.arrResult.removeAllObjects()
            for mp in response.mapItems{
                self.arrResult.addObject(mp)
            }
            self.searchTable.reloadData()
 }
```

**Code for add Annotaion into map at click on result (UITableview)**

```
 var mItem : MKMapItem = arrResult[indexPath.row] as MKMapItem
        var ann : MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView()

        ann.annotation.setCoordinate!(mItem.placemark.coordinate)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(ann.annotation)
```

Please help me. I stuck with this issue.

Comment: You don't add MKAnnotationViews - you need to add an MkAnnotation - either your own class that adopts the MKAnnotation protocol or an MKPointAnnotation

Comment: Wow. I add MKPointAnnotaion.And it charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding an `MKAnnotationView` to the map rather than an `MKAnnotation` - You either need to add an instance of a class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol or an `MKPointAnnotation`